# Apk install behaving differently from developer install - Android?

Tags: android, installation, android-actionbar, apk

I created an apk of an application I'm working on. Going through all the normal steps - building a key store with eclipse - it auto signs it for you and spits out a .apk file.

*However strangely, the .apk install behaves differently from my developer install of the same application.*

I have an action bar(using actionbar sherlock) with a home button in the top left corner, that should causes a navigation menu to slide out from the left. This happens on my developer install, but not in the .apk version of the same application.

I did look through stack overflow for a similar question, but I've mostly found installation errors, or signage problems. I also have an app on the market, and never came across this problem before - so creation of .apk files is not new to me.

***Question :***

**What could the problem be and has this ever happened to you?**

Comment: bling guessing: proguard "eat" something?

Comment: I thought that could be the problem, but proguard is responsible for obfuscating and shrinking code, and getting rid of method names that are never used. It's like a code clean-up/ security mechanism that's built in to save you space. I don't see how it would get rid of something that is of core-functionality to the application, at least that's not how I expect it to behave.

Comment: obfuscating some times is done by changing the name of methods and classes ... if some library are using reflection on classes not excluded from obfuscation you may end with errors/undefined behavior ... still it's just bling guessing ...

Comment: Hmmm good point there! 
I'm going to look more into how to setup proguard the way I want it setup - especially on my libraries. If this leads me in the right direction, you should post your idea's as an answer so I can accept it.